# How to decode encrypted soap messages with PHP

Tags: php, soap, encryption, ws-security

I'm having massive problems with encrypted SOAP messages within PHP
We're getting data like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" 
  xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" 
  xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
 <dsig:KeyInfo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <xenc:EncryptedKey Recipient="name:[NAME]">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
        <dsig:KeyInfo>
            <dsig:KeyName>[KEY_NAME]</dsig:KeyName>
        </dsig:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>[RSA_ENCRYPTED_PK]</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedKey>
 </dsig:KeyInfo>
 <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
 <xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:CipherValue>[ENCRYPTED_DATA_HERE]</xenc:CipherValue>
 </xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
```

I can find the following information 
http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/how-does-soap-message-encryption-work
but can't manage to decrypt the message

I have the correct private key

This is part of s SAML-2 iDP post

Does anyone know how / a PHP library which could help please?

Yours

Tim

Answer (score 0):

try using http://simplesamlphp.org/ to setup your Service Provider.